# XSLT: How to select value from the object based on the particuar value from an JSONX array object

Tags: arrays, xslt, jsonx

From the below example I need to extract the data of "value" field., when the string field name = "first". How should write the xpath in XSLT for the below JSONX sample to get the desired result.

Example:

```
<json:array name="filters">
<json:object>
<json:object>
<json:string name="name">first</json:string>
<json:string name="op">eq</json:string>
<json:string name="value">11223333</json:string>
</json:object>
<json:object>
<json:string name="name">second</json:string>
<json:string name="op">eq</json:string>
<json:string name="value">1234</json:string>
</json:object>
<json:object>
<json:string name="name">date</json:string>
<json:string name="op">between</json:string>
<json:string name="value">26/07/2016</json:string>
<json:string name="value2">26/07/2018</json:string>
</json:object>
</json:object>
</json:array>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to get the output as `11223333`?

Comment: Yes...the output should be 11223333, when name = 'first'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
//json:object[json:string[@name='name']='first']]
   /json:string[@name='value']/string()
```

(with a suitable namespace binding of course)

Comment: @ApupaKS, the SO way of saying "Thankyou, it worked" is to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the tick/check mark next to the answer. That way the question is registered as having an accepted answer.